# How to make dynamic width div in 3 columns css flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make 3 column layout with flex box. The goal is to make first and last div widths dynamic. But the 2nd div `max-width` is static.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    
        <style>
        
        html, body{
    
            min-height: 100% !important;
            height: 100%;
        }
    
        body{
    
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #ddd;
    
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    
        .left , .center, .right{
    
            height: 100%;
        }
    
        .left{
            width: auto;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
        }
    
        .center{
    
            display: flex;
            min-height: 100vh;
            flex-direction: column;
            
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1200px;
    
            background-color: green;
        }
    
        .right{
            
            width: auto;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="left">
    
        </div>
    
        <div class="center">
    
        </div>
    
        <div class="right">
    
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now I am getting the `center` max width is constant that I expected. But `left` & `right` div's not appear always. I want to make `right` & `left` div appear with dynamic width that based on browser window size.

Update - current layout:

[image]

Expected layout:

[image]

How can I make it work?

Comment: I reduced the center column width from 1200px to 200px to test on my smaller window, and it seems to be working as you need.

Comment: @valangar, Sorry I don't want to reduce center column width. It should be max 1200px. So, After 1200px `left` & `right` will appear with dynamic width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

Just apply `flex:1` to all of the divs **but** `flex: 1 0 100%;` to the center div so it defaults to as wide as it can before hitting the `max-width` you wanted.

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
}

.left,
.center,
.right {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: auto;
  background-color: red
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.right {
  width: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">

</div>

<div class="center">

</div>

<div class="right">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```css
 .flex-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   background-color: DodgerBlue;
 }

 .flex-container > .side {
   background-color: green;
   width: 100%;
 }


 .flex-container > .center {
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   color: green;
   max-width: : 100%;
   height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="center">
   this will expand as your content grows
  </div>
  <div class="side"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, It's not worked expected.. I just need dynamic width for `side` but want to `width:100%, max-width:1200px` for `center`.